# conditional probability: Bayes or not?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I'm learning about conditional probabilities and the Bayes theorem, but I don't know how to really think about it. The problem I have is the following:

There are 50 men and 40 women at a workplace. 10% of the men and 2.5% of the women smoke. When choosing an employee at random, we happen to choose a smoker. What is the probability that the smoker is female?

My solution idea is the following, but I'm not sure it's correct.

Let M = men, F = female, S = smoker.

We want

P(F | S) = P(F $\cap$ S) / P(S)

Here

P(F $\cap$ S) = 0.025

P(S) = (0.1*50 + 0.025*40) / 90 $\approx$ 0.0667.

Thus:

P(F | S) $\approx$ 0.025 / 0.0667 $\approx$ 0.37

What makes me suspicious of that this might be wrong is that I'm uncertain if it's correct to say P(F $\cap$ S) = 0.025. It may be that this should be P(S | F) meaning that I could use the Bayes theorem P(F | S) = P(S | F) P(F) / P(S).

Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: $\Pr(F\cap S)=(0.025)(40/90)$. You actually almost calculated this on your way to finding $\Pr(S)$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}P(S) ~=~& P(M\cap S)+P(F\cap S) \\[1ex] ~=~& \frac{ 0.1\cdot 50 + 0.025\cdot 40 }{90} & \text{...which you had.} \\[2ex]\therefore ~ P(F\mid S) ~=~& \frac{ 0.025\cdot 40 }{ 0.1\cdot 50 + 0.025\cdot 40 } \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a tree illustrating the problem.

$$\begin{cases} men \ \  5/9 & \begin{cases}10\% \  smoker \\ non-smoker \end{cases} \\ female  \ \ 4/9 & \begin{cases} 2.5\%\  smoker \\ non-smoker \end{cases} \end{cases} $$

If you compute probability of intersections. For example $P(F\cap S) = 4/9\cdot 0.025$ because when considering the event $F\cap S$ we must keep in mind the probability of $F$ and that of $S$.

On the other hand if we have $P(S|F)$ then we have the fact that the person is female as an assumption (just like it would have probability $1$) so we do not look at the $4/9$ probability hypothesis.

In conclusion, if you use Bayes you get $P(F|S) = P(F\cap S)/P(S)$. We have $P(F\cap S) = 4/9\cdot 0.025$ and $P(S) = 5/9\cdot 0.1+4/9\cdot 0.025$.

Therefore $P(F\cap S)$ is not $0.025$. That is the value of $P(S|F)$.